# jQuery Datatable javascript on links not working with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, plugins, datatable

I am having an issue with jQuery's Datatable plugin... I have filled a table, and a specific column has cells looking like this:

```
<a href="26" name="PO">12</a>
```

I have prevented the onclick event and it triggers this code:

```
$( 'a[name="PO"]' ).click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var POid = $( this ).attr('href');
            var element = $( this );
            $( '<div id="Dialog">\
                <p class="error"></p>\
                <p style="text-align:center;" class="main">Entrez le P.O. associé à la commande</p>\
                <input type="text" class="POprompt"/>\
                </div>').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 'auto',
                width:'400',
                modal: true,
                title: 'Ajout d\'un PO',
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'drop',
                buttons:{
                    "Sauvegarder":function() {
                        $('.error').css('color','FF0000');
                        var prompt = $('.POprompt').val();
                        if (!isNaN(parseInt(prompt)))
                        {
                            $.post('setPO.php',{'PO':prompt,'id':POid},function(data)
                            {
                                element.text( prompt );
                                $('.main').css('color','#0F0');
                                $('.POprompt').css('visible','false');
                                $('.main').text("L\'ajout a été effectué avec succès.")
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                $('.error').text("");
                                $('.error').css('color','#FFF');
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var error = $('.error');

                            error.text("Veuillez entrer des chiffres seulement.");
                            error.addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                error.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                            }, 1000 );
                        }
                        $('.error').css('color','FF0000');
                    },
                    "Annuler":function() 
                        {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }       
                }
            } );
        });
```

But when I go on page 2 or 3, or when I sort results and click on that cell link but that the row was generated in another page than the first one, the javascript does not trigger.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot in advance guys, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got everything to work fine by adding this:

```
"bLengthChange": true,
```

to my datatable declaration.

I also modified the `<select>` options, adding a "show all" option which loads all the rows by default, but only shows 5 rows on pageload since I set `"iDisplayLength": 5`.
Here is how to add a "show all" value to your length select input (sum):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').dataTable({
        "bLengthChange":true,
        "bFilter":true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "sDom":'<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oLanguage":{
            "sUrl": "dataTables.txt"
        }
    });
});
```

The text file contains all your translations (if you need them) and your custom SELECT:

```
{
    "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Show <select><option value=-1>INFINITE</option></select> results"
}
```

Note: of course I added other options to my select AND datatable declaration, it is just easier to read this way. The `value=-1` part is how to get javascript to load on ALL rows/cells.

Thanks to the guys who tried helping me out, both of your answers were useful to me!

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this question has been answered, however, it's incomplete and with all due respect possibly wrong. The issue with the mutipage datatable is that the initial selector is rendered useless with the user clicks on ANY of the pages other than the default first page. This is because dataTable does some horrible things to the DOM in order to render the table. This has the side effect of disabling your click handler.

The good news is that there is a way to handle this other than listing ALL elements.

instead of...

`$( 'a[name="PO"]' ).click(function(){`

try this:

`$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on('click', 'a[name="PO"]',  function(){`

Read this jquery page ( [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ) and look for the section on deferred selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Because when the javascript insert element to document it doesn't have onclick. jQuery will not add onclick to them, automatically.

**Solution:** Call this script every time data loaded (when user changes page or sorts table).